# Migradoc Image in paragraph line

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have pdf cover page where i have 5 paragraph lines, and over for those 5 paragraph line i need to be able to add a logo picture, so it will looks something like this :

```
Pragraph 1                                            First part of picture
Pragraph 2                                            Second part of picture
Pragraph 3                                            Third part of picture
Pragraph 4                                            fourth part of picture
Pragraph 5                                            fifth part of picture
```

Any ideas?

Right now if i create 5 lines and put a picture with wrapperformat set to through it just ends over or under paragraph lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the right margins of the paragraphs to keep text and image apart.

With WrapFormat == through, images are ignored while laying out text - that's by design.

It's up to you to set paragraph margins to keep text and images separated if that's what you want.

You can set the margin for a paragraph (as shown below) or better create a style and assign that style to all paragraphs on the frontpage:

```
Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph("Some text ...");
paragraph.Format.RightIndent = "6cm";
```

See the DefineStyles routine in this sample for further information about styles:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx