# How to generate an RTF document server side in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rtf

I have tried using the System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument server side, but ran into a problem with images.

What I need to produce is a document with headings, section breaks, page breaks, images (with text wrapping around from the left or the right), tables and ideally some kind of table of contents.

I use c# and asp.net.

Is there a library that will do most of this?

RTF has been chosen because the document needs to be openable in older versions of word, be editable, and we can't run word on the server.

Thank-you

Comment: When you say "server side" what do you mean?  Is this a web application?  Is it a desktop Win Forms or WPF application?  What technologies are you using?  Just saying the language is C# isn't enough for us to go on.

Comment: Sorry @Jim.  I am using asp.net.  I would like to generate the a file on the server, and stream it to the client.  there is no desktop win form application.  I tried to use the FlowDocument object (not RichTextBox) in code (in asp.net), but I don't think that is how it was intended to be used (I wasn't fully expecting it to work, it is just the first answer to every question about rtf I have found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started using [.net rtf writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netrtfwriter/).

It produces clean rtf, but doesn't do everything I need.

There is pretty good documentation for rtf [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140302%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

I am working some things out for my self. For example, I needed to be able to wrap text around an image.  Whilst the rtf writer above enables you to add images to documents, it does so by putting the image in its own paragraph.  What I need is a [shape element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx#rtfspec_27).

In the rtf it ends up looking something like this (some of the numbers define the size and position of the image in twips):

```
{\shp{\*\shpinst\shpleft3801\shptop1\shpright8300\shpbottom4500\shpfhdr0\shpbxcolumn\shpbxignore\shpbypara\shpbyignore\shpwr2\shpwrk0\shpfblwtxt0\shpz0
{\sp
{\sn pib}
{\sv
{\pict\pngblip\pichgoal4499\picwgoal4499
-- image binary data goes here --
}}}
{\sp
{\sn fLine}
{\sv 0}}}}
```

I sometimes just save something in word and try and understand what it did (but word seems to add a lot of noise).

Answer (score 1):

I used MigraDoc in the past, it is a free library.   You can create PDFs or RTFs. Just Google it.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea how you might get text to wrap around an image in MigraDoc.  I can't find any example.

Comment: I didn't have to do that, but this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622530/migradoc-image-in-paragraph-line